# Find all upper, lower and mixed case permutations of a string

Tags: vba

**Background:**

In collecting data we wanted associate each item of data with individuals who contributed it but without actually identifying them individually. To do this we used `MD5(Environ("UserName"))` and stored this 'ID' on each of the individual contributors PCs. The unforeseen problem that thwarted our plan was that under some conditions windows changes the case of `Environ("UserName")`, probably depending on how the user logs in. This incorrectly flagged that the user was unregistered and prevented them from contributing.

Having learned from our mistake we now use lowercase version of the UserName to anonymize respondents: `MD5(lCase(Environ("UserName")))`.

But we still need to re-validate each user who was flagged as un-registered and rewrite their MD5 IDs. Part of this strategy means checking the current MD5 is in-fact for this user, i.e. systematically change case until a match is found then rewrite the MD5 based on `lCase(UserName)`; this is the crux of the question.

**Problem:**

I have a need to find all possible combinations of a string between `lCase(string)` and `uCase(string)` - without rearranging characters. For example, given the input string of: `abc` I would expect the code to return: `abc, abC, aBc, aBC, Abc, AbC, ABc, & ABC`.

The following code does that, but perhaps not as efficiently as it could. I'm working on the following assumptions:

- the input characters will be limited to:

  - upper and lower case characters, A-z
  - regular numbers, 0-9
  - regular space character, " "
- the input strings are relatively short, 1 to 20 characters
- Users typically log into Windows using:

  - FirstMiddleLast,
  - FLast
  - FMLast
  - FirstL, etc.
  - (but other combinations and cases are also possible & likely)

The code basically works by converting an input string to lower case and [then into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/999270/3451115). This provides each character in the input string with an easy-to-access index.

The next step is to create a binary number with 1 digit for each character in the input string. Then starting from `000` (i.e. for `abc`) use a loop to keep adding 1 (to a decimal number and converting) to binary until there are no zeros left in the binary number. For each iteration of the loop the "1's" in the binary number represent possible uppercase characters for the original input string.

On my test PC it takes approximately 60 seconds to process a 16 character input string. I'm sure there is room for improvement.

In addition to speed I would like to better structure the code so that it is easier to test and so that when I look at it later I'm not left cursing myself.

The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Const BASE_2 As Long = 2
Const CHR_1 As String = "1"
Const CHR_0 As String = "0"

Public Sub CasePermutation(ByVal stringPassed As String)
    Dim stringIn As String

    stringIn = LCase$(stringPassed)
    Const SKIP_BLANKS As Long = 2


    Dim stringInArray() As Byte
    stringInArray = stringIn  'Assign Unicode string to bytes.'

    Dim caseToggleArray() As Byte

    Dim exponent As Long
    exponent = Len(stringIn)

    Dim maxDecimal As Long
    maxDecimal = BASE_2 ^ exponent

    Dim decimalNumber As Long

    For decimalNumber = 0 To maxDecimal - 1

        caseToggleArray = DecToBin(decimalNumber, exponent)

        Dim positionInString As Long
        For positionInString = LBound(stringInArray) To UBound(stringInArray) Step SKIP_BLANKS
            Dim tempString As String
            If Chr$(caseToggleArray(positionInString)) = CHR_1 Then
                tempString = tempString & UCase$(Chr$(stringInArray(positionInString)))
            Else
                tempString = tempString & Chr$(stringInArray(positionInString))
            End If
        Next positionInString

        Debug.Print tempString

        ' Reset for next iteration
        tempString = vbNullString
    Next decimalNumber

End Sub


Public Function DecToBin(ByVal decimalPassed As Long, ByVal digitsToCount As Long) As String
    Dim curDec As Long
    curDec = decimalPassed
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim positionInString As Long
    positionInString = digitsToCount

    Do While positionInString >= 0
        If curDec >= (BASE_2 ^ positionInString) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & CHR_1
            curDec = curDec - (BASE_2 ^ positionInString)
        Else
            If positionInString <> digitsToCount Then
                strTemp = strTemp & CHR_0
            End If
        End If

        positionInString = positionInString - 1
    Loop

    DecToBin = strTemp
End Function

Public Sub test()
    Dim myNow As Date
    myNow = now()
    CasePermutation "a 1"
    Debug.Print now & " " & myNow ' rough but ok for testing with 16 chr input strings
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for the slowdown is the repeated "Debug.Print" command. Store your results in an array instead, and "print" it to a worksheet. Just by making that change, the time elapsed was reduced to 1.2 seconds on my computer.

There are a few other slowdowns (like using the "Chr$()" function twice every time through the inner loop) but nothing major.

My reworked version processed a 16-character string + printed the results in 0.6 seconds on my computer, approximately twice as fast as the slightly reworked original code. I find it somewhat easier to read (mostly due to avoiding the Byte arrays) but that may just be personal preference. The logic is similar in both.

EDIT: Slightly modified to avoid use of Application.Transpose, which caused errors with >16 characters in string.

```
Sub casePermutation(ByVal str As String, destWS As Worksheet)

    'Loop through characters in string and record whether they are "flippable"
    '(ie whether they are a letter from a-z)
    ReDim flippable(1 To Len(str), 1 To 2) As Variant
    str = LCase(str)
    Dim numLetters As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        flippable(i, 1) = Mid(str, i, 1)
        Dim aVal As Long
        aVal = Asc(flippable(i, 1))
        If aVal >= 97 And aVal <= 122 Then
            flippable(i, 2) = True
            numLetters = numLetters + 1
        Else
            flippable(i, 2) = False
        End If
    Next

    'Alert user if character limit has been exceeded
    If numLetters > 20 Then
        MsgBox "Error: Function only supports up to 20 ""flippable"" letters"
        Stop
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill array of permutations
    ReDim resultsArr(1 To 2 ^ numLetters, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim toRepeat As Long
    toRepeat = 1
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        Dim uBool As Boolean
        Dim repeatCounter As Long
        Dim j As Long
        uBool = False
        repeatCounter = 0
        For j = 1 To UBound(resultsArr, 1)
            If flippable(i, 2) = True Then
                If repeatCounter >= toRepeat Then
                    uBool = Not uBool
                    repeatCounter = 0
                End If
                If uBool = False Then
                    resultsArr(j, 1) = resultsArr(j, 1) & flippable(i, 1)
                Else
                    resultsArr(j, 1) = resultsArr(j, 1) & UCase(flippable(i, 1))
                End If
                repeatCounter = repeatCounter + 1
            Else
                resultsArr(j, 1) = resultsArr(j, 1) & flippable(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
        If flippable(i, 2) = True Then
            toRepeat = toRepeat * 2
        End If
    Next

    'Paste results to destination sheet
    With destWS
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(resultsArr), 1)) = resultsArr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have a look and get back to you 

Comment: Nice. There is 1 *big* difference in the logic - your code is processing the permutations concurrently whereas mine is processing the permutations sequentially. This is something that I never anticipated and it is really cool to see how other people approach problems differently; and educational too. Now I see the need to be more specific with stating requirements (and I guess seeking clarification).

Comment: I did notice your code generates Error 13 for strings larger than 16 characters: `casePermutation "abcdefghijklmnop", activeworkbook.Sheets(1)` on this line `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(resultsArr), 1)) = Application.Transpose(resultsArr)`. I didn't test the impact of non-flippable characters.

Comment: I'll update my question to provide some more clarity as to why I am looking to generate the permutations sequentially - basically it is so I can exit the code if I find a match with text in another location.  E.g. `If EncodePermutation = someString Then Stop`. I *think* this forces the sequential approach as (unstated in the OP) each permutation is encoded and checked against a string.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks. I always forget about that Application.Transpose bug, I've run into it a couple of times. Luckily it's an easy fix, just have to turn it into a fake "2d" array.

Comment: Oh, transpose bug - I was wondering.  Not an Excel user... At any rate I only need one of the permutations so I have been testing the code without outputting anywhere. I have been running each permutation through the encoder and your code is ~4% faster for "abcdefghijklmnopq" and ~8% faster for "abcdefghijklmnopqrst". But since my code can exit sooner (as soon as the first match is found) it will probably be faster *(the pragmatic approach)* in application.

Comment: Huh, interesting. You *might* be better off using a Dictionary instead of an array to store the results. Then instead of doing separate string comparisons after each permutation, you can do

    resultsDict.Exists("yourstring")

Which is much faster at checking for the existence of a value as the number of values to check increases. My guess is that it'd have better average-case performance than yours, but worse best-case performance. But it'd take some testing to know for sure.

Comment: Well that was interesting your code blew mine completely out of the water on my first few tests with real data (which happen to be names like `FirstMiddleLast` --> `100001000001000` - then I modified my code slightly and it became even faster, but only because it hits the exit condition sooner due to the way expected patterns are matched.  Will need to update the question to explain properly.

Comment: So after much testing and speculation I decided to add some initial guesses rather than using Brute Force straight away. The initial guesses try to predict common patterns as per 'typical' user name patterns like Mr X: IhaveareallylongfirstnameX would take some time with brute force, but is quick to guess. Will post the revised code as a solution once it is tidied up some more.

Comment: In case you're interested, see initial guesses below. Many thanks for your help :-D

Comment: Sure thing! Glad I was of some help.

Answer (score 1):

**About this Answer**

Thanks to Daniel McCracken for his thoughts on this. Daniel's answer was a great solution to the original question; hence his is the accepted answer.

This answer suits my needs better but those needs could not have been guessed from the original question.  However...

After considering Daniel's proposal I realized that it might be appropriate to make some guesses before launching into what was essentially a Brute Force approach to solving my problem which is essentially to generate all possible Upper/Lower case permutations of a username and compare that to an encrypted string.

**Declarations**

```
Option Explicit

Const BASE_2 As Long = 2
Const CHR_1 As String = "1"
Const CHR_0 As String = "0"
```

**Fake MD5**

For the purpose of testing I created FakeMD5:

```
Function fakeMD5(ByVal inputString As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String
    Dim outputString As String
    For i = 1 To Len(inputString)
        c = Mid(inputString, i, 1)

        If UCase(c) = c Then
            outputString = outputString & CHR_1
        Else
            outputString = outputString & CHR_0
        End If
    Next i

    fakeMD5 = outputString

End Function
```

FakeMD5 generates a string of '0' and '1' to represent upper and lower case characters in the UserName *(e.g. `UserName` => `10001000`)*.

For some tests Daniel's code blew mine out of the water - I was surprised because he generated string permutations concurrently so all permutations have to be generated before any can be tested. On the other hand my code generates permutations sequentially allowing testing to be done sooner for some permutations.

**Initial Tweak to DecToBin**

Looking at Daniels code it became obvious that his code was producing strings that would likely match real usernames before my code would. This realization prompted two slight modifications in the method DecToBin (which incidentally mandates a rename):

```
        If curDec >= (BASE_2 ^ positionInString) Then
            'strTemp = CHR_1 * strTemp
            strTemp = strTemp & CHR_1  '                   <= Modified
            curDec = curDec - (BASE_2 ^ positionInString)
        Else
            If positionInString <> digitsToCount Then
                'strTemp = CHR_0 & strTemp
                strTemp = strTemp & CHR_0  '               <= Modified
            End If
        End If
```

This change meant the binary string was reversed and therefore would match a normal UserName sooner *(i.e. string is built like this: `10000000, 01000000, 11000000` instead of `00000001, 00000010, 00000011`)*.

***[EDIT: Overhaul of DecToBin]*** (still needs a name change)

After posting this answer some more thought went into DecToBin... essentially the problem requires adding 1 to a binary number... there is no need to recalculate the binary number so it is declared as `Static`.

The DecToBin function was replaced with the following code to yield a better than 30% improvement in overall speed:

```
Public Function DecToBin(ByVal decimalPassed As Long, ByVal digitsToCount As Long) As String

    Static binaryR As String
    Static zeros As String
    Dim iPos As Long
    Dim iZero As Long

    Select Case True
        Case decimalPassed = 1, 0
            binaryR = vbNullString
            For iPos = 1 To digitsToCount
                binaryR = CHR_0 & binaryR
            Next iPos
            zeros = binaryR
            binaryR = CHR_1 & binaryR

        Case Mid$(binaryR, 1, 1) = CHR_0
            Mid$(binaryR, 1, 1) = CHR_1

        Case InStr(binaryR, CHR_0) = 0
            ' this is the end
            For iPos = 1 To digitsToCount
                binaryR = CHR_0 & binaryR
            Next iPos

        Case Else
            iPos = InStr(binaryR, CHR_0)
            Mid$(binaryR, iPos, 1) = CHR_1
            Dim iCount As Long
            For iCount = 1 To iPos
                Mid$(binaryR, iCount, 1) = CHR_0
            Next iCount

    End Select

    DecToBin = binaryR
End Function
```

***Note:*** *An attempt was made to eliminate the `For` Loop in favor of using `Mid$()` (code below was proposed rewrite of Dec2Bin with name change) but it turns out the `Mid$()` was slower than using a loop. The test strings for this were all 1 lowercase character followed but 'n' uppercase characters.*

```
Function binaryAddOne() As String ' Expected to be fast, but was slow NOT Used (see results: 'Old Shift')
    Static zeros As String
    Static binin As String
    Dim iPos As Long

    iPos = InStr(1, binin, CHR_0)

    Select Case True
        Case binin = vbNullString
            zeros = Replace$(Space$(30), " ", CHR_0)
            binin = Replace$(zeros, CHR_0, CHR_1, 1, 1)

        Case CBool(iPos)
                Mid$(binin, iPos, 1) = CHR_1
                Mid$(binin, 1, iPos - 1) = Left$(zeros, iPos - 1)

    End Select
    binaryAddOne = binin
    'Debug.Print binin

End Function
```

In the image below times are in seconds (calculated  `(Now(End) - Now(start)) * 10 ^ 5` , "Loop" is the time for the original code (as in OP), and "Shift" is the time for adding `+1` using BinaryAddOne() *(instead of recalculating the entire binary number)*. Surprisingly "Old Shift" was the result when using `Mid$()` to replace zeros instead of looping through the characters to replace zeros.

[image]

**Opportunity for CasePermutation**

Nothing was changed in the method CasePermutation.

There might be some opportunity to do away with the `Byte` array by using the builtin `Mid` function to modify strings.

**Initial Guesses**

The `Mid` function is used in the newly added `InitialGuesses` method, code:

```
Private Function InitialGuesses(ByVal stringIn As String, ByVal encrypted As String) As String
    Dim tempString As String
    Dim i As Long
    tempString = LCase(stringIn)
    Dim testString As String

    ' All UpperCase
    If fakeMD5(UCase(tempString)) = encrypted Then
        InitialGuesses = UCase(tempString)
        GoTo foundResult
    End If

    ' Only letter is Cap
    For i = 1 To Len(stringIn)
        'testString = Left(tempString, i - 1) & UCase(Mid(tempString, i, 1)) & Right(tempString, Len(tempString) - i)
        testString = tempString
        Mid(testString, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(tempString, i, 1))
        If fakeMD5(testString) = encrypted Then
            InitialGuesses = UCase(testString)
            GoTo foundResult
        End If
    Next i

    ' First letter + 1 other letter is Cap
    For i = 2 To Len(tempString)
        testString = tempString
        Mid(testString, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(tempString, 1, 1))
        Mid(testString, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(testString, i, 1))
        If fakeMD5(testString) = encrypted Then
            InitialGuesses = testString
            GoTo foundResult
        End If
    Next i

    ' First letter + 2 consecutive letters are Cap
    For i = 2 To Len(tempString) - 1
        testString = tempString
        Mid(testString, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(tempString, 1, 1))
        Mid(testString, i, 2) = UCase(Mid(testString, i, 2))
        If fakeMD5(testString) = encrypted Then
            InitialGuesses = testString
            GoTo foundResult
        End If
    Next i

    ' First letter + 2 letters separated by a space (XxxxxXxX) are Cap
    For i = 2 To Len(tempString) - 2
        testString = tempString
        Mid(testString, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(tempString, 1, 1))
        Mid(testString, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(testString, i, 1))
        Mid(testString, i + 2, 1) = UCase(Mid(testString, i + 2, 1))
        If fakeMD5(testString) = encrypted Then
            InitialGuesses = testString
            GoTo foundResult
        End If
    Next i

foundResult:
End Function
```

Initial guesses is designed to quickly test likely combinations of case permutations based on typical UserNames. The last two guesses were included for people with surnames like OBrien and McCracken (or with initials in their names like VerySLearner).

**Testing the Code**

The whole thing is driven by this test method:

FakeMD5 creates a string that for all intents and purposes serves as our unique ID for a given user - it is generated from `myTestString` and is used to compare each permutation against.

Compare the speed of finding a match for a very long first name using initial guesses and brute force by commenting out the line: `stringFound = InitialGuesses(myTestString, encrypted)` *(word of warning this could take a while, hold Ctrl+Esc before pressing Ctrl+Break works for me, you could add DoEvents in the main For loop of CasePermutation)*

```
Sub test()
    Dim myNow As Date
    Dim myNow2 As Date
    Const myTestString As String = "Daniel_has_a_longnameMcCracken" ' Change this for testing 
    Dim encrypted As String
    encrypted = fakeMD5(myTestString)
    Debug.Print "Encrypted by fakeMD5: " & encrypted & " (" & Len(encrypted) & ")"
    Dim stringFound As String

    myNow = Now()
    Debug.Print "Attempting initial guesses..."
    stringFound = InitialGuesses(myTestString, encrypted)

    If stringFound <> vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print stringFound
        GoTo foundID
    End If

    Debug.Print "Initial guesses failed, attempting brute force..."


    stringFound = CasePermutation(myTestString, encrypted)


    If stringFound <> vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print stringFound
        GoTo foundID
    End If

foundID:
    Debug.Print "v1 " & (Now - myNow) * 10 ^ 5 ' rough estimate of time
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```